# Rewrite matrix equation as $By=0$

Tags: matrices

I am stuck with the following matrix equation:

Solve for $X$:

$$X=AXA^{T}$$

where $A$, $X$ are $3\times 3$ (real) matrices and $X$ is symmetric (i.e. $X=X^{T}$).

The sketch for the solution is to rewrite the above equations as:

$$By=0$$

where $B$ should be a $6\times 6$ matrix and $y$ should be a 6-vector. Then the solution is obvious. But how to rewrite the above equation without spending lots of paper?

I know the equation can be written in the form:

$$A^{-1}X=XA^{T}$$

and be solved as [Discrete Lyapunov Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation) or a [Sylvester Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) in general, but since both sides contain $A$ and no addition of extra element, the solution may be simpler. Furthermore, I expect the matrix $X$ to be in a particularly simple form (symmetric or even diagonal matrix).

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Comment: I take it you're looking for a symmetric $X$?  There may also be antisymmetric solutions.

Comment: Yes, the $X$ should be symmetric. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: You see how to obtain the form $By=0$ correct? I don't immediately see a way that doesn't involve actually multiplying out $AXA^T$ (which would be the "spending lots of paper" part, I presume).

Comment: I am trying to get $By=0$ from the product by hand, but since the problem yields such linear system, I suggest there should be some straightforward analytical/numerical solution to obtain $X$.

Comment: Here's a special case with path leads to *nothing*. But I want to write it down anyways. Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A^{T}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda = \pm 1.$ Let $u = Xv.$ Note in this very special case $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $A^{-1},$ with an eigenvector $u.$ Multiply $A^{-1}X = XA^{T}$ by $v,$ to get $A^{-1}Xv = X\lambda v.$ It is easy to see that $Xv = u,$ where both $u$ and $v$ are known. Not interesting system to solve though..

Comment: I think that you need to specify $A$ (or properties of it) if you expect to find solutions in a more or less explicit way: because otherwise you can have, say, $A=I$, and then any $X$ is a solution.

Comment: Also, $X=0$ is always a solution.

Comment: copprer.hat - yes, but there is nonzero (nontrivial) solution as well

Comment: Martin: The problem arises in calibration of a rotating camera. Here $H$ is a common linear transform between images in a projective space. The only thing I know is that $H = KRK^{-1}$ where $K$ is the upper-triangular calibration matrix and $R$ is the rotation matrix. But I don't know $R$ and to solve for $K$ without knowing $R$ leads to the above equation.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. I recommend you to read the paper "a flexible new technique for camera calibration" by zhang zhengyou. Look at eq. (6). B is a 3 by 3 symmetric matrix, and b is the associated 6D vector. Although this paper is for camera calibration, I think the technique is transferable. Just an idea and a suggestion

Comment: Thanks Shiyu - I actually need the solution for camera calibration.  I currently let $X$ to be in a very simple form $X=diag(f,f,1)$ where $f$ corresponds to focal length. Multiplying right hand side of the above equation and equating components of left and right matrices leads to a simple least squares problem. The results are precise enough, but it would be nice to allow for more complex calibration matrix $X$ in future (the off-diagonal elements allow to grasp aspect ratio, skew and principal point of the camera)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use paper, use silicon.  The matrix $B$ (for the basis $x_{1,1},x_{1,2},x_{1,3},x_{2,2},x_{2,3},x_{3,3}$) is 
$$\pmatrix{ 1-{a_{{1,1}}}^{2}&-2\,a_{{1,2}}a_{{1,1}
}&-2\,a_{{1,3}}a_{{1,1}}&-{a_{{1,2}}}^{2}&-2\,a_{{1,3}}a_{{1,2}}&-{a_{
{1,3}}}^{2}\\ -a_{{1,1}}a_{{2,1}}&1-a_{{1,2}}a_{{2,1
}}-a_{{1,1}}a_{{2,2}}&-a_{{1,3}}a_{{2,1}}-a_{{1,1}}a_{{2,3}}&-a_{{1,2}
}a_{{2,2}}&-a_{{1,3}}a_{{2,2}}-a_{{1,2}}a_{{2,3}}&-a_{{1,3}}a_{{2,3}}
\\ -{a_{{2,1}}}^{2}&-2\,a_{{2,2}}a_{{2,1}}&-2\,a_{{2
,3}}a_{{2,1}}&1-{a_{{2,2}}}^{2}&-2\,a_{{2,3}}a_{{2,2}}&-{a_{{2,3}}}^{2
}\\-a_{{1,1}}a_{{3,1}}&-a_{{1,2}}a_{{3,1}}-a_{{1,1}
}a_{{3,2}}&-a_{{1,3}}a_{{3,1}}+1-a_{{1,1}}a_{{3,3}}&-a_{{1,2}}a_{{3,2}
}&-a_{{1,2}}a_{{3,3}}-a_{{1,3}}a_{{3,2}}&-a_{{1,3}}a_{{3,3}}
\\ -a_{{2,1}}a_{{3,1}}&-a_{{2,2}}a_{{3,1}}-a_{{2,1}}
a_{{3,2}}&-a_{{2,3}}a_{{3,1}}-a_{{2,1}}a_{{3,3}}&-a_{{2,2}}a_{{3,2}}&-
a_{{2,3}}a_{{3,2}}+1-a_{{2,2}}a_{{3,3}}&-a_{{2,3}}a_{{3,3}}
\\ -{a_{{3,1}}}^{2}&-2\,a_{{3,2}}a_{{3,1}}&-2\,a_{{3
,3}}a_{{3,1}}&-{a_{{3,2}}}^{2}&-2\,a_{{3,3}}a_{{3,2}}&1-{a_{{3,3}}}^{2
}} 
$$

In order to have a nonzero solution, the determinant of $B$ must be $0$.
This is a rather complicated polynomial of total degree 12, which factors over the rationals as 
$$
- ( a_{{2,3}}a_{{3,1}}a_{{1,2}}-a_{{1,2}}a_{{2,1}}-a_{{2,1}}a_{{1
,2}}a_{{3,3}}+1+a_{{1,1}}+a_{{2,2}}+a_{{1,1}}a_{{2,2}}-a_{{1,3}}a_{{3,
1}}-a_{{2,2}}a_{{3,1}}a_{{1,3}}+a_{{2,1}}a_{{3,2}}a_{{1,3}}-a_{{2,3}}a
_{{3,2}}-a_{{1,1}}a_{{2,3}}a_{{3,2}}+a_{{3,3}}+a_{{1,1}}a_{{3,3}}+a_{{
2,2}}a_{{3,3}}+a_{{1,1}}a_{{2,2}}a_{{3,3}} )  ( a_{{2,3}}a_
{{3,1}}a_{{1,2}}+a_{{1,2}}a_{{2,1}}-a_{{2,1}}a_{{1,2}}a_{{3,3}}-1+a_{{
1,1}}+a_{{2,2}}-a_{{1,1}}a_{{2,2}}+a_{{1,3}}a_{{3,1}}-a_{{2,2}}a_{{3,1
}}a_{{1,3}}+a_{{2,1}}a_{{3,2}}a_{{1,3}}+a_{{2,3}}a_{{3,2}}-a_{{1,1}}a_
{{2,3}}a_{{3,2}}+a_{{3,3}}-a_{{1,1}}a_{{3,3}}-a_{{2,2}}a_{{3,3}}+a_{{1
,1}}a_{{2,2}}a_{{3,3}} )  ( -1-a_{{1,3}}a_{{3,1}}-2\,a_{{1,
2}}a_{{1,3}}{a_{{2,1}}}^{2}a_{{3,2}}a_{{3,3}}-2\,{a_{{1,2}}}^{2}a_{{2,
1}}a_{{2,3}}a_{{3,1}}a_{{3,3}}-2\,a_{{2,1}}{a_{{1,3}}}^{2}a_{{2,2}}a_{
{3,1}}a_{{3,2}}-2\,a_{{1,1}}a_{{1,2}}{a_{{2,3}}}^{2}a_{{3,1}}a_{{3,2}}
-2\,a_{{1,1}}a_{{1,3}}a_{{2,1}}a_{{2,3}}{a_{{3,2}}}^{2}-2\,a_{{1,2}}a_
{{1,3}}a_{{2,2}}a_{{2,3}}{a_{{3,1}}}^{2}-a_{{1,1}}a_{{1,3}}a_{{2,1}}a_
{{3,2}}+a_{{1,1}}a_{{1,3}}a_{{2,2}}a_{{3,1}}+a_{{2,3}}a_{{2,2}}a_{{1,1
}}a_{{3,2}}+a_{{2,1}}a_{{1,2}}a_{{1,1}}a_{{3,3}}+a_{{2,2}}a_{{2,1}}a_{
{1,2}}a_{{3,3}}-a_{{2,3}}a_{{3,1}}a_{{1,2}}a_{{3,3}}+a_{{2,2}}a_{{3,1}
}a_{{1,3}}a_{{3,3}}-a_{{2,1}}a_{{3,2}}a_{{1,3}}a_{{3,3}}+a_{{1,1}}a_{{
2,3}}a_{{3,2}}a_{{3,3}}-a_{{2,1}}a_{{2,2}}a_{{3,2}}a_{{1,3}}-a_{{2,2}}
a_{{2,3}}a_{{3,1}}a_{{1,2}}-a_{{1,1}}a_{{1,2}}a_{{2,3}}a_{{3,1}}+a_{{1
,3}}{a_{{2,2}}}^{2}a_{{3,1}}+{a_{{1,1}}}^{2}a_{{2,3}}a_{{3,2}}-a_{{2,2
}}{a_{{3,3}}}^{2}a_{{1,1}}+{a_{{1,1}}}^{2}{a_{{2,2}}}^{2}{a_{{3,3}}}^{
2}-{a_{{1,1}}}^{2}a_{{2,2}}a_{{3,3}}+{a_{{1,1}}}^{2}{a_{{2,3}}}^{2}{a_
{{3,2}}}^{2}-a_{{1,1}}{a_{{2,2}}}^{2}a_{{3,3}}+{a_{{1,2}}}^{2}{a_{{2,3
}}}^{2}{a_{{3,1}}}^{2}+{a_{{1,3}}}^{2}{a_{{2,2}}}^{2}{a_{{3,1}}}^{2}-2
\,a_{{1,1}}a_{{1,2}}a_{{2,1}}a_{{2,2}}{a_{{3,3}}}^{2}+{a_{{1,2}}}^{2}{
a_{{2,1}}}^{2}{a_{{3,3}}}^{2}+a_{{2,1}}{a_{{3,3}}}^{2}a_{{1,2}}+{a_{{1
,3}}}^{2}{a_{{3,2}}}^{2}{a_{{2,1}}}^{2}+2\,a_{{1,2}}a_{{2,3}}a_{{3,2}}
a_{{2,1}}a_{{1,1}}a_{{3,3}}-2\,{a_{{2,2}}}^{2}a_{{3,3}}a_{{1,3}}a_{{1,
1}}a_{{3,1}}+2\,a_{{2,1}}a_{{2,2}}a_{{3,3}}a_{{1,3}}a_{{1,2}}a_{{3,1}}
+2\,a_{{1,3}}a_{{3,2}}a_{{2,3}}a_{{2,2}}a_{{1,1}}a_{{3,1}}+2\,a_{{1,2}
}a_{{1,3}}a_{{2,1}}a_{{2,3}}a_{{3,1}}a_{{3,2}}+2\,a_{{1,1}}a_{{1,2}}a_
{{2,2}}a_{{2,3}}a_{{3,1}}a_{{3,3}}+2\,a_{{1,1}}a_{{1,3}}a_{{2,1}}a_{{2
,2}}a_{{3,2}}a_{{3,3}}-2\,{a_{{1,1}}}^{2}a_{{2,2}}a_{{2,3}}a_{{3,2}}a_
{{3,3}}-a_{{1,2}}a_{{2,1}}+a_{{1,1}}a_{{2,2}}+a_{{1,1}}a_{{3,3}}-a_{{2
,3}}a_{{3,2}}+a_{{2,2}}a_{{3,3}} ) 
$$

Comment: Thanks for the thorough solution. Maybe I overlooked some information about the matrices, since the final system really should be linear.

Comment: Linear in $X$, but not linear in $A$.

Comment: Oh, right. Now I know why people go so often for iterative methods when it comes to such problems...